# How to apply table cell formatting using CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm having some difficulty with my CSS formatting of a cell in a table.  The cell needs to have a different background color, column span and alignment than the other cells in the table.  In-line styling works fine, but I want to move the styling to CSS.

Here's what I have in my CSS:

```
/*Color and formatting the background on cal_parameter*/
.calParameter
{
background-color:darkgray;
column-span:all;
align-content:center;
}
```

For some reason, the column-span and align-text properties are not applied by CSS, but the background-color is.

This in-line styling works right:

```
<td class="calParameter" colspan="8" align="center">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => data.cal_points.cal_parameter)</td>
```

This CSS styling doesn't work right:

```
<td class="calParameter">@Html.DisplayFor(modelitem => data.cal_points.cal_parameter)</td>
```

TIA,
~~~Tracy

Comment: In your dev console, can you see the other values being overridden by other css?

Comment: None that I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.calParameter {
background-color:darkgray;
text-align:center;
}
```

Keep the colspan attribute and get rid of the align attribute. Change your css to what I have above. colspan is an attribute made for html td's.

Comment: Thank you!  Replacing "align-content" with "text-align" works.  I don't quite understand what you mean about colspan being an attribute for html td's.  I am only apply this style to html table td's. Perhap's I need to change the CSS to specify table instead of just a generic class?

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, hope it will resolve your issue.

For cell spacing use:

```
table {border-spacing: 8px 2px;}
```

For cell padding use:

```
td{padding: 6px;}
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond!  Your response doesn't tell me why the "column-span" in my style sheet isn't working.... while "colspan" in-line does.

Comment: There are some limitations in css using tables, CSS does many things really very well. Tables are not among them. 

That may not be the popular answer, but I believe it to be the honest one.

You can achieve similar thing that you are trying to do via using div and making them act as a table through css. 

I am posting a example separately in my next answer.

Comment: Thanks again!  I didn't realize that there's a difference between "CSS tables" and "HTML tables" - I'm a jack-of-all trades, master-of-none!  Since I only render this particular data on one page, I'll just leave it as in-line code.

Answer (score 0):

**You are misusing CSS properties!**

`colspan` has no css equivalent. it's TD table **HTML attribute**, while `column-span` makes an element span across columns, and only works with other elements using `column-count`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-span

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  Is there a way to accomplish this "column span" using CSS?  I tried adding column-count to my css followed by the column-span, but stil no luck

Answer (score 0):

Try this out, it worked well for me, hope it will be useful to you as well.

```
<div class="tablewrapper">
  <div class="table">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Top left
      </div>
      <div class="rowspanned cell">
        Center
      </div>
      <div class="cell">
        Top right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="cell">
        Bottom left
      </div>
      <div class="empty cell"></div>
      <div class="cell">
        Bottom right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.tablewrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.table {
  display: table;
}
.row {
  display: table-row;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table-cell;
}
.cell.empty
{
  border: none;
  width: 100px;
}
.cell.rowspanned {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
```

For more info, you can go through this elaborated example.